# awk: Compare two sets of numbers (generated by random and strict rules)

Tags: awk, grep

I have many files containing some fixed words and numbers:
The FIRST SET of numbers has a fixed length of 7 digits: the first 4 of them being like a random prefix (in example are 100,200,300 but can be others..) we do not need it, we are interested for the remaining 4 digits.
The SECOND SET of number/s is generated number based on the last 4 digits from the FIRST SET (xxx7777 = 7777; xxx0066 = 66). You can see that the SECOND SET can NOT have leading zeros, they are cut out already and this is a rule.

**Input**

```
first second third 1007777 fourth 7777
...
first second third 2008341 fourth 8341
...
first second third 3000005 fourth 5
...
...
first second third 2008341 fourth 8
...
first second third 2008341 fourth 341
```

I found in other examples here - how to find interested lines using grep, but I didn't found AWK example doing what I want, because of the rule with the leading zeros maybe i'm having problems..

**My attempt** to find the wrong generations:

```
grep -Pr 'first second third' docs/test/*.txt | awk '{ if($4=$6) print $4 " " $6}'

7777 7777
8341 8341
5 5
8 8
341 341
```

The correct **Output** should look like this:

```
2008341 8
2008341 341
```

..only the problems (not right generated) lines and the filename.

Thanks ! :)

Comment: `$4=$6` is an assignment. You meant `$4==$6` for a test. There's other issues too of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/first second third/ && (substr($4,4)+0 != $NF) {print FILENAME, $4, $NF}' file
file 2008341 8
file 2008341 341
```

Call it as:

```
awk '...' docs/test/*.txt
```

or:

```
find docs -name '*.txt' -exec awk '...' {} \;
```

or similar as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks ! Works very well when I made test. One question, because i'ts turn out that my actual data (which I did not have access to when I asked) the strings are **arranged** diferently and when I made changes to your solution dosen't work :(  
**first 1007777 second 7777 third**   `awk '/first/ && (substr($2,4)+0 != $NF) {print FILENAME, $2, $NF}' test.txtr`

Comment: You're welcome. Change $NF to $4 just like you changed $4 to $2.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [gnu](/questions/tagged/gnu) way, intented to be human readable and maintenable :

```
$ grep -r foobarbase . | awk '
    {match($4, /[0-9]{4}$/, a);            #1
    a[0]=gensub(/^0+/, "", "g", a[0])}     #2
    $NF != a[0]                            #3
' file
```

### Output :

```
first second third 2008341 fourth 8
first second third 2008341 fourth 341
```

### Explanations :

- ```
  #1
  ```

  get the last 4 digits of column 4 and assign `a` array with match
- ```
  #2
  ```

  remove all leading 0
- ```
  #3
  ```

  if cutted part is different than last column, `print` (default awk behavior on true condition)